# rxbag_plugins commandline API

Tags: ros, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to call the rxbag_plugins from commandline? More specific the plot functionality, I'm thinking of the rxplot api but more specific the CSV export function. Are there any plans on this or similar functionality?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9388/rxbag_plugins-commandline-api/) by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The plugins are only for use in rxbag. You could write your own CSV export script for bag files, or just use rostopic. There is a command line option for rostopic that allows echoing a bagfile in a machine-readable format.

---

Originally posted by [watts](https://answers.ros.org/users/99/watts/) with karma: 584 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0